# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: icon. I'm trying to use v-icon with v-if but when using change the variable I get this warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome

I'm trying to use v-icon with v-if but when using change the variable I get this warning

Below is the Vue code:

```
<v-col cols="6" xs="12" md="2" lg="2" xl="2">
    <span class="span_titulo">Valor Unitário:</span>
    <div class="form-group m-1">
        <v-text-field class="mt-0" type="text" maxlength="6" disabled v-model="form.vlrUnit" hide-details>
                    <template v-slot:append>
                        <v-icon v-if="vlrUp === null" v-icon color="green" left>fa-solid fa-brazilian-real-sign</v-icon>
                        <v-icon v-else-if="!vlrUp" v-icon color="green" left>fa-solid fa-turn-down</v-icon>
                        <v-icon v-else v-icon color="red" left>fa-solid fa-turn-up</v-icon>
                    </template>
              </v-text-field>
    </div>
</v-col>
```

return recive [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: icon
I'm initializing the variable with NULL, Why is this warn generated?

Comment: Hey, can you please tell, me why are you using `v-icon` prop and what is this for? Isn't simply `<v-icon v-if="vlrUp === null" color="green" left>fa-solid fa-brazilian-real-sign</v-icon>` working?

Comment: is this a one directive for Vuetify for import ICONS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `v-icon` directive from the `<v-icon>` component:

```html
<v-col cols="6" xs="12" md="2" lg="2" xl="2">
  <span class="span_titulo">Valor Unitário:</span>
  <div class="form-group m-1">
    <v-text-field class="mt-0" type="text" maxlength="6" disabled v-model="form.vlrUnit" hide-details>
      <template #append>
        <v-icon :color="vlrUp === true ? 'red' : 'green'" left>
          fa-solid
          {{ vlrUp === true ? 'fa-turn-up' : vlrUp === false ? 'fa-turn-down' : 'fa-brazilian-real-sign' }}
        </v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
  </div>
</v-col>
```